# MyBatis get resultMap as String

Tags: mybatis

I need to get from the database uniqe list if values in one column (type String). But if I try to set

```
<select id="getAllValues" parameterType="map" resultMap="java.lang.String">
        SELECT distinct value_id FROM values
    </select>
```

I receive the error - Result Maps collection does not contain value for java.lang.String
How can I get a list of Stings from the database via MyBatis?

Comment: You need to use `resultType` i.e. `resultType="java.lang.String"`. Please read the [doc](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#select).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to ave, I've found the solution:

```
<select id="getAllValues" parameterType="map" resultType="java.lang.String">
        SELECT distinct value_id FROM values
    </select>
```